# How do I treat ground cherry tips being eaten completely off?

Tags: insects, back-to-eden

I have ground cherry tips that are getting eaten completely off every few days. How should I treat this without harming the beneficial insects?

The plant is still showing leaves after watering, but the leaves disappear soon after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to keep them well watered and to use floating row covers over them. 
Another option is a product called Thuricide.  It's a bacteria that ONLY affects leaf-eating insects and caterpillars.  Will not kill any beneficials.
Hope this helps!